# Fill formula for entire column without filesize explosion in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there some way to apply a formula down to the entire column, without defining a specific one (e.g. from `#Calculate!A2` till `#Calculate!A9999`) and thus avoiding a filesize explosion for use cases where huge data are copy-pasted into a table that it references to?

i.e. consider a case where you create a calculation worksheet, that has formulas referencing a worksheet where you insert a database export (with several 10'000 rows).

I'm aware that this use case is easy to solve with some VBA, but I'd like to know whether there's a possibility without adding a "make calculation" button.

Comment: Would a [Table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) work for your needs? It uses calculated columns that stores the formula once along with the structure that it applies to every cell in that column of the table. IE, a table with 10,000 rows would have the formula in the save file once rather than 10,000 times. There may be some messiness in importing your data but, from my experience, the table will grow automatically to fit data if you paste in more rows that it currently has.

Comment: Not entirely clear on how your data appear and where your calculations are performed, so this may not help. Would it help if you added a row_number to your data sheet, and then your calculations apply where that row number is under 10,000.

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data with us especially all about the column where U wana formula to copy effortlessly !

Comment: @RajeshS There you go
https://www.file-upload.net/download-14417088/example-workbook.xlsx.html

Comment: @PatMächler,, unfortunately this link is not working !!

Comment: @RajeshS That's odd. I see a blue "download" button there :-/